# Column with Foreign key to itself

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys

I am working with a large existing database and found a few strange things. Among them is this Primary key with a Foreign key that seems to reference itself. Can anyone think of why this is set up this way? I would like to remove all of these, but don't want to break anything just because I don't understand it.

```
ALTER TABLE [career].[AssignmentRange] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_AssignmentRange] 
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
     [AssignmentRangeID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [career].[AssignmentRange]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT 
[FK_AssignmentRange_AssignmentRange] FOREIGN KEY([AssignmentRangeID])
REFERENCES [career].[AssignmentRange] ([AssignmentRangeID])
GO
```

Comment: If you don't understand it, don't touch it!

Comment: There is no reason to do this unless you want to prevent inserts into the table.

Comment: Yes, there are cases when self-referencing foreign keys make sense.

Comment: I started to write a long explanation about composite patterns, with self pointers, but I stopped when I came to the point that the referencing key literally points to the same field. That is very strange indeed.

Comment: @ jarlh "self-referencing foreign keys" refers to the same table, not the same field. Can you please explain what sense is to reference the same field?

Comment: Thank you so far! It's good to know it's not something obvious I've missed. But troublesome that it isn't consensus on "delete is ok"

Comment: @GordonLinoff I just tried, and succeeded with an Insert on that table. In what way would the self-join hinder that?

Comment: >>>I just tried, and succeeded with an Insert on that table.<<< Of course it succeeded. SQL Server generates absolutely identical plans for insert when there is this super-self-reference-same-column and when there is no FK on that same column, so **it really changes nothing** if there is or there is not. And those persons who upvoted that comment ("unless you want to prevent inserts into the table") made their conlusion looking at the reputation only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't serve any purpose, as you can tell by the comments below.

The only actual use for that instruction would be to avoid some shenanigans like a `truncate` from a stored procedure, or something similar, and whoever made this doesn't know it can be done with permissions.

Either that, or the author was cluelessly testing.

Comment: Did you read the code or the comments? It's not just the same table it's the same field. It's a primary key which is a foreign key to itself at the same time.

Comment: How would this block DDL instructions? I tried an Insert, and it worked as usual.

Comment: Try to use a `truncate` and see if it deletes anything. Theoretically it shouldn't let you `truncate`, but you'll be allowed to `delete from`, which makes sense from a management point of view.

Comment: >>> Theoretically it shouldn't let you truncate, but you'll be allowed to delete from<<< TRUNCATE and DELETE require different permissions and if you don't want your table to be truncated just grant no permission to do it

Comment: If someone has ALTER TABLE (is able to do TRUNCATE) he can effectively drop any FK on that table. So there is NO protection from TRUNCATE anyway

Comment: @sepupic that's why I said it's a hack. I would personally get rid of it as it doesn't serve any purpose whatsoever, whatever they were trying to do can be done properly using permissions... or it was just some clueless person trying some luck...

Comment: I agree with this: **it doesn't serve any purpose**

Comment: Since we agree on that much, and it's pretty straightforward, I just edited the answer to reflect that.